# EFCore Include function works in Get endpoint but does not work in Put endpoint

Tags: ef-core-3.1

Hi I am working with IdentityServer4 and EFCore 3.1.0 recently and have a very weird issue with the following two pieces of code. The result is that in `ApiResourcesGetByIdController`, `apiResource` in `GetById` function includes the value of scope and secret. However in `ApiResourcesUpdateController`,  `result` in `Update` function does not include the value of scope and secret.

The usage of these two endpoints is that, the frontend calls the `GetById` endpoint to get ApiResource object and makes some modification in frontend. Then the frontend calls `Update` endpoint to update the object in database.

Can anyone help to see what could be wrong? Thank you

```
[Authorize]
[Route("ApiResources")]
[ApiController]
public class ApiResourcesGetByIdController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ConfigurationDbContext _configurationDbContext;

    public ApiResourcesGetByIdController(
            ConfigurationDbContext configurationDbContext)
    {
        _configurationDbContext = configurationDbContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult GetById([FromQuery]int id)
    {
        ApiResource apiResource = _configurationDbContext.ApiResources
            .Include(apiResource => apiResource.Scopes)
            .Include(apiResource => apiResource.Secrets)
            .FirstOrDefault(apiResource => apiResource.Id == id);

    }
}


[Authorize]
[Route("ApiResources")]
[ApiController]
public class ApiResourcesUpdateController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ConfigurationDbContext _configurationDbContext;

    public ApiResourcesUpdateController(
        ConfigurationDbContext configurationDbContext)
    {
        _configurationDbContext = configurationDbContext;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult Update([FromBody] ApiResource resource )
    {
        ApiResource result = _configurationDbContext.ApiResources
            .Include(apiResource => apiResource.Scopes)
            .Include(apiResource => apiResource.Secrets)
            .FirstOrDefault(ar => ar.Id == resource.Id);

        return Ok()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but I deleted the file and recreated it. Then it works by itself.